# Magnetic field through walls

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

Is it possible to measure magnetic field from a household ac (50Hz) conductor inside a wall?

Comment: I'm not certain enough to put this as an answer but i figure that since we're dealing with ac we would not have a static field, and this we'd have an em-wave from the wires at 50Hz which would be a wavelength of some 400 metric miles, which can't be measured unless your antenna is a minimum 200+ metric miles. So i'd say, no. But i am not 100% certain.

Comment: This might be a good question for [SE.ElectricalEngineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Or for [diy.se]

Comment: One can certainly by ammeters that go around a cable to measure current, and they do so through the magnetic field. But, they have a loop around the wire. Inside a wall is, of course, harder.

Comment: which of the two wires do you want to measure the magnetic field of, hot or neutral?

Answer (score 1):

Detecting magnetic field produced by a $50$Hz household AC cable, with or without the wall, could be difficult for a couple of reasons.

First, in the absence of a load, the current in the wires and, therefore, the magnetic field, would be extremely low.

Second, there are two opposite and equal currents flowing in a hot and neutral wires and the magnetic fields of these two currents largely cancel each other at a distance from the cable.

The frequency does matter, when we choose the type of a current sensor, but even a DC current could be detected (for instance, by a compass), as long as it flows in one direction at a time.

It is much easier to detect the electric field (for instance, with a piece of wire connected to a scope probe), which is going to be present around an AC cable regardless of the load. The changing AC voltage in a hot wire will produce a changing electric field, which will induce voltage in the pick-up wire.

Comment: I think I downvoted this answer by accident, so sorry about that. It won't let me undo the downvote unless the answer is edited, but I don't really want to edit your answer lol.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I've edited the answer (added a comma), so, if you feel like it, you can undo your downvote.

Comment: lol ok, done...